# Kotlin: Executing function stored in a variable

Tags: android, kotlin, lambda, higher-order-functions

I am trying to create a function in `Kotlin` that takes a block of code, and execute it if the app is in foreground, else store it in a variable and execute it the next time app comes in foreground.

**What I have done till now:**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var appInBackground = false
    private var codeBlock: Any? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        appInBackground = false
        if (codeBlock!=null)
            performOperations { codeBlock }
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle?) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        appInBackground = true
    }

    fun performOperations(block: () -> Unit) {
        if (appInBackground)
            codeBlock = block
        else {
            block()
            codeBlock=null
        }
    }
}
```

I am calling the function as:

```
mainActivity.performOperations {
    val fm=mainActivity.supportFragmentManager
    for (i in 0 until fm.backStackEntryCount)
        fm.popBackStackImmediate()
}
```

**The problem that i am facing:**

If the app is in foreground and i call the `performOperations` method, the block of code passed as argument gets executed. But, if i store the block of code in a variable and try to call the `performOperations` method on `onResume`, the block of code is not executed.

P.S: There might be errors in my code, because i am a beginner in Higher Order Functions and Lambdas.

Comment: You should not reference paused activity at all and reflect any data changes in your `onResume` block exclusively.

Comment: But i don't have control over it. Suppose  I wan't to replace `HomeFragment` with `LoginFragment` on `Logout` api response. But the response of `Logout` api arrives while the app is in background. How should i handle this case?

Comment: In that case, your callback should apply UI changes only if the activity is in foreground, otherwise store the result in variable. 
When activity is resuming, if there is a result saved and never processed, you do it!
And I would implement it with onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState rather than only with onResume

Comment: @LucaCorradi that sounds promising.

Comment: @LucaCorradi but instead of storing the response, i was thinking about storing the code block that would be executed once the app comes in foreground. Is that possible? How can i achieve it? Thats why i was trying for the lambda appraoach.

Comment: As mentioned by Pawel it's not advisable to keep a reference to a code block that could keep a strong reference to the activity instance. It could drive to a retain cycle or inconsistencies.
Depending on how much time the activity remains in background, it could be even destroyed.
Saving it both in a private var and serializing with onsavedinstance state can be safest.
Or you could use the ViewModel from architecture components that is designed to survive through the activity's lifecycle. It would be probably the best solution, but you should adopt it as a design pattern in your application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, I wouldn't recommend following this pattern to resolve your issue. LiveData/ViewModel is definitely a preferred solution so that your long-running events can persist in a lifecycle outside of your UI, and only deliver the result when your Activity is visible.

That said, to answer the question, you need to store the code block as a function so that you can invoke it. In your `performOperations` method, you take in a parameter of type `() -> Unit`, but you store it as an `Any?`. The former can be invoked, while the latter cannot (it could literally be any type).

To fix, you can change it to:

```
private var codeBlock: (() -> Unit)? = null
```

And invoke with:

```
codeBlock?.invoke()
```